# Handling exceptions when reading/writing file

Tags: java

I am trying to read from a file, but i just don't get it how can i do so while using a try catch block ... How can i make it throw exception if something bad happens, but if it's ok to execute this line : br.readLine() ? It just say that br is not declared. What if i need to use "br" and "bw" somewhere different(like a different method) ? Do i have to declare them there too ?

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

br is declared in the scope of the try and therefore is gone after the catch. You want to do this:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
br.readLine();
```

Note you risk the null pointer after the catch so another option would be to write the br.readLine() into the try, like this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    br.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader and BufferedWriter should be define outside from try and catch block than only we can access them outside
Try this code, it should work


     BufferedReader br = null;
             BufferedWriter bw =null;
             try {
                  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                  bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared BufferedReader and BufferredWriter within the try block and calling br.readline() outside the try and catch and hence it doesn't know where the br has been declared. I have the same answer as above.

```
try {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File ("path_to_your_file_to read")));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path_to_your_file_to_write")));
br.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```